# Pandas how to perform the inner calculation in the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing the employee id, age, and experience, I need to calcaute the age and experience based on the logic

Input dataframe

| emp_id | name | age | exp | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2000 |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2001 |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2002 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2000 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2001 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2002 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2000 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2001 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2002 |

Expected output

| emp_id | name | age | exp | YEAR | update_age | upadted_exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2000 | 18 | 3 |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2001 | 19 | 4 |
| 101 | Rock | 20 | 5 | 2002 | 20 | 5 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2000 | 23 | 8 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2001 | 24 | 9 |
| 102 | DED | 25 | 10 | 2002 | 25 | 10 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2000 | 28 | 33 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2001 | 29 | 34 |
| 103 | FEG | 30 | 35 | 2002 | 30 | 35 |

Explanation

Logic 1- If the employee has 3 records with age and experience, needs to subtract the last record values from the above 2. Emp_id is unique.

Second Module

I have below data frame based on the max year I need to update the year column. ie - year emp_id 101 have 3 records, max year = 2001 so output column contains 2001,2000,1999

| emp_id | name | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rock | 2000 |
| 101 | Rock | 2000 |
| 101 | Rock | 2001 |
| 102 | DED | 2002 |
| 102 | DED | 2002 |
| 102 | DED | 2000 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 |

Output

| emp_id | name | year | upadte_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rock | 2000 | 1999 |
| 101 | Rock | 2000 | 2000 |
| 101 | Rock | 2001 | 2001 |
| 102 | DED | 2002 | 2000 |
| 102 | DED | 2002 | 2001 |
| 102 | DED | 2000 | 2002 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 | 1998 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 | 1999 |
| 103 | FEG | 2000 | 2000 |

Comment: FYI: I've edited your dfs, turning all `103` values that match `DED` into `102`, assuming these were typos. Please let me know if this is *not* correct, and I'll rollback the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output as follows. Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `emp_id` and retrieve the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for each group in descending order. Next, subtract the result from cols `age` and `exp` to get your updated columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'emp_id': {0: 101, 1: 101, 2: 101, 3: 102, 4: 102, 5: 102, 
                   6: 103, 7: 103, 8: 103}, 
        'name': {0: 'Rock', 1: 'Rock', 2: 'Rock', 3: 'DED', 4: 'DED', 
                 5: 'DED', 6: 'FEG', 7: 'FEG', 8: 'FEG'}, 
        'age': {0: 20, 1: 20, 2: 20, 3: 25, 4: 25, 5: 25, 6: 30, 
                7: 30, 8: 30}, 
        'exp': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10, 6: 35, 
                7: 35, 8: 35}, 
        'YEAR': {0: 2000, 1: 2001, 2: 2002, 3: 2000, 4: 2001, 
                 5: 2002, 6: 2000, 7: 2001, 8: 2002}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cumcount = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount(ascending=False)

df['updated_age'] = df['age'].sub(cumcount)
df['updated_exp'] = df['exp'].sub(cumcount)

print(df)

   emp_id  name  age  exp  YEAR  updated_age  updated_exp
0     101  Rock   20    5  2000           18            3
1     101  Rock   20    5  2001           19            4
2     101  Rock   20    5  2002           20            5
3     102   DED   25   10  2000           23            8
4     102   DED   25   10  2001           24            9
5     102   DED   25   10  2002           25           10
6     103   FEG   30   35  2000           28           33
7     103   FEG   30   35  2001           29           34
8     103   FEG   30   35  2002           30           35
```

---

**Update**: as for the *second question added later*: to add the column `updated_year` to the second `df` based on the `max` in column `year` for each `emp_id`, try as follows:

```
df['updated_year'] = df.groupby('emp_id')['year'].transform(max)\
    .sub(df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount(ascending=False))

print(df)

   emp_id  name  year  updated_year
0     101  Rock  2000          1999
1     101  Rock  2000          2000
2     101  Rock  2001          2001
3     102   DED  2002          2000
4     102   DED  2002          2001
5     102   DED  2000          2002
6     103   FEG  2000          1998
7     103   FEG  2000          1999
8     103   FEG  2000          2000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if I want to calculate the year similar like this .i.e if the emp_id = 101 have 3 record , minim year is 2000, I need add one column update_year = 2000 , 2001 , 2002. (consider the current data contain year like 2000,2000,2001 for emp 101)

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly here. You already have `df.YEAR` with e.g. `[2000,2001,2002]` for `emp_id == 101`. Do you mean: how do I get a column with all the start years for each `emp_id`, e.g. `[2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000]` in this case? Or do you mean: *if* `df.YEAR` looked like: `[2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000]`, how would you turn that into the `df.YEAR` you actually already have? Please clarify.

Comment: thank you so much I have updated the question in main can you check pls.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with your project. If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that you want to correct `age` and `exp` based on the actual year-differences (I might be wrong, though). If that's the case, you could try:

```py
diff = df["YEAR"] - df.groupby("emp_id")["YEAR"].transform("max")
df["update_age"] = df["age"] + diff
df["update_exp"] = df["exp"] + diff
```

- Build a `diff` series that contains the difference in years between `year` and the maximum year per `empty_id`.
- Correct `age` and `exp` using `diff`.

Result for the sample (corrected):

```
   emp_id  name  age  exp  YEAR  update_age  update_exp
0     101  Rock   20    5  2000          18           3
1     101  Rock   20    5  2001          19           4
2     101  Rock   20    5  2002          20           5
3     102   DED   25   10  2000          23           8
4     102   DED   25   10  2001          24           9
5     102   DED   25   10  2002          25          10
6     103   FEG   30   35  2000          28          33
7     103   FEG   30   35  2001          29          34
8     103   FEG   30   35  2002          30          35
```